# t-sql how to subtract two records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, subtraction, sql-timestamp

I have such a query:

```
SELECT Stamp_date , Stamp_Action FROM FILES_TIME_STAMPS
WHERE Stamp_File_Id = @FileID AND Stamp_Action IN (5,15)
```

And I have such a results from query:

```
2017-12-04 12:56:37.293 5

2017-12-04 15:40:02.593 15
```

What is the best way to subtract two records? Also how can I define them as a variables, if I would like to maintain with them easily?

Comment: I think you need `row_number` or `top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to subtract this two dates you can use `DATEDIFF` and `MIN` -`MAX`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Stamp_date) , MAX(Stamp_date)) FROM FILES_TIME_STAMPS
WHERE Stamp_File_Id = @FileID AND Stamp_Action IN (5,15)
```

you can change `MINUTE` to `SECOND` or other `datepart` according to your need

Also if you want select MIN and MAX according to Stamp_Action you can use this.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN Stamp_Action = 5 THEN Stamp_date END)  , 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Stamp_Action = 15 THEN Stamp_date END ) ) 
FROM FILES_TIME_STAMPS
WHERE Stamp_File_Id = @FileID AND Stamp_Action IN (5,15)
```

Comment: It is working! Also how can I maintain them as a different unique values, maybe as variables? For example if there would be more records, but I need to have only that specific date? Because there could be 3 records with id 5 for example , but I need to pick most oldest or most recent date.

Comment: I'm afraid it would work only in this particular case. But if it does its job, it's good :)

Comment: @BinaryTie you can use CASE in the MAX and MIN function

Answer (score 1):

It's good example for applying `LAG` function:

```
declare @x table([date] datetime, [value] int)
insert into @x values ('2017-12-04 12:56:37.293', 5), ('2017-12-04 15:40:02.593', 15)

select *,LAG([date], 1) over (order by [date]) [DateLag],
       LAG([value], 1) over (order by [date]) [ValueLag],
       DATEDIFF(minute, [date],LAG([value], 1) over (order by [date])) [DateDifference],
       [value] - LAG([value], 1) over (order by [date]) [ValueDifference]
from @x
```

I included as much examples as I could, so you can decide what you need and could see how it works :)